# Help on limiting range and domain for critical points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've been working on some simple scripts to find critical points. I've been using this one.

[image]

Where the red script is the particular function I'm interested in.

But I am struggling to find a way to calculate the critical points when the domain and/or range is limited.

For example, I'm interested in finding the critical points of f(x,y) = sin(x)sin(y) ,`f[x_,y_]=Sin[x] Sin[y]`, where `-pi =< x =< pi`, and `-pi =< y =< pi`. Here's the code I use, and, absent the limits on x and y, it gives a wild unusable answer. But I get errors when I try to mess around with limiting x and y to their respective range and domain. Here's the basic function, sans limits on x and y.

```
ResourceFunction["StationaryPoints"][Sin[x] Sin [y], {x, y}]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try e.g.: Solve[{Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, -Pi <= x <= Pi, -Pi <= y <= 
   Pi}, {x, y}]

Answer (score 1):

```
ResourceFunction[
  "StationaryPoints"][{Sin[x]*
   Sin[y], -π <= x <= π && -π <= y <= π}, {x, y}]
```

> `<|"Saddle" -> {{0, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}, {0, {x -> 0,  y -> -π}}, {0, {x -> 0, y -> π}}, {0, {x -> -π,  y -> 0}}, {0, {x -> -π, y -> -π}}, {0, {x -> -π,  y -> π}}, {0, {x -> π, y -> 0}}, {0, {x -> π,  y -> -π}}, {0, {x -> π, y -> π}}},  "Maxima" -> {{1, {x -> -(π/2),  y -> -(π/2)}}, {1, {x -> π/2, y -> π/2}}},  "Minima" -> {{-1, {x -> -(π/2),  y -> π/2}}, {-1, {x -> π/2, y -> -(π/2)}}}|>`